# Getter and setter like behavior in one closure

Tags: javascript

Learning javascript and i am trying to write a simple closure that encapsulate a variable which i can set or get.
here is an example of the behavior i am aiming for specifically:

```
let x = Field(1) //set value to 1, return the closure itself
x(2)             //set value field to 2
x()              //returns 2
x(3)             //set value to 3
x()              //returns 3
```

is it possible to do the above and preserve the same exact syntax, i imagined that i should make the closure return itself but when i tried that it obviously lost the value field and created a new instance:

```
/**
 * if v is passed it functions like a setter
 * if no arguments passed it functions like a getter
 * @param {*} [v] 
 */
const Field = function(v){
    let value
    if (arguments.length === 1) { //SET
        value = v;

    } else if (arguments.length === 0) { //GET
        return value;
    } else {
        throw 'Field can have one or no arg'
    }

    return Field //how to i return this exact instance of Field?
}
```

My question as per the last code comment, how do i return this exact instance of Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const Field = function(v) {
    this.value = v;

    return function() {
        if (arguments.length === 1) { //SET
            this.value = arguments[0];
        } else if (arguments.length === 0) { //GET
            return this.value;
        } else {
            throw 'Field can have one or no arg'
        }
    }.bind(this);
}

let f = new Field(42);
console.log(f());

f(51);
console.log(f());
```